# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection in JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc

Below is my code which I am trying to connect.

```
public Connection Connect() throws SQLException{
        try
          {
              DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
              OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
              ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:TSOFT1/TSOFT1@10.184.132.130:1521/FCUTILS");
              con = ods.getConnection();
              return con;
          }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            con.close();
            return null;
          }
   }
```

I tried to search an answer for this but nothing worked.

Comment: Try doing a ping and tnsping to the IP address.

Comment: Hi @user75ponic when I am doing ping its showing as connected when I am doing tns ping its showing error message as TNS-12541: TNS:no listener.

Comment: If it is showing `TNS:no listener`, then you need to start the listener. Google to find how to start the listener or inform the DBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest take this actions:

1.- Make sure your Etherneth cable is pugled on 
2.- Try to ping the ip: 10.184.132.130
3.- Is The Data Base Server on?
4.- Change your OrcleDataSource to this:

```
 OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
 dataSource.setDriverType(DRIVER_TYPE);
 dataSource.setServerName(SERVER_NAME);
 dataSource.setPortNumber(PORT_NUMBER);
 dataSource.setDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME);
dataSource.setUser(userName);
dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
```

This line you wrote:

```
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:TSOFT1/TSOFT1@10.184.132.130:1521/FCUTILS");
```

Doesn't seems good I think your user name and password are TSOFT1, but don't you have to write it like this?

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:TSOFT1:TSOFT1@10.184.132.130:1521/FCUTILS"
```

Hope it can help you.

Here are some examples taht may help you.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Comment: Hi @Yussef I tried using this url dbc:oracle:thin:TSOFT1:TSOFT1@10.184.132.130:1521/FCUTILS". Its showing the error as Invalid URL specified

Comment: my bad i forgot to put a j at the first place it should be like this: jdbc:oracle:thin:TSOFT1:TSOFT1@10.184.132.130:1521/FCUTILS and if it doesn't work it could be like jdbc:oracle:thin:TSOFT1:TSOFT1@//10.184.132.130:1521/FCUTILS   can you try please?